# define a directory for including a file

Tags: php

I'm currently working on my first independent project, I'm looking to keeping my code to the best standard possible, I've been looking in the PHP manual but I seem to be missing how to cleanly define a directory to include, for example my templates folder is 'templates/default' and I'd like to define that once.

```
TEMPDIR = templates/default
require_once (__DIR__ . '/TEMPDIR/header.php');
```

if anyone could guide me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__ . "/" . TEMPDIR . "/header.php");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack.

I guess that you want to define a constant `TEMPDIR` and then use it in the `require_once()`.

To define a variable please use `define()` (please see manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

```
<?php define('TEMPDIR', 'templates/default');
```

To use constant in the `require_once()` you have to do a string concatenation (please see manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs):

```
<?php require_once (__DIR__ . '/' . TEMPDIR . '/header.php');
```

You should also consider using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to make sure that you use separators which will work on any OS (please see manual http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php):

```
<?php require_once (__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . TEMPDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR 'header.php');
```

Cheers!

Comment: Fantastic, that's just what I was looking for, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `require` line is treating `TEMPDIR` as part of a string literal:

```
TEMPDIR = templates/default
require_once (__DIR__ . '/TEMPDIR/header.php');
```

Try:

```
 TEMPDIR = templates/default
 require_once (__DIR__ . '/' . TEMPDIR . '/header.php');
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried your code but it gives me a blank page, I have error reporting on but no errors are displayed.

Comment: Hmmm, what's header.php actually doing? There's a few things that could be the cause...is the path being fed to `require` actualy valid?

Comment: it has the contents of a html header document inside

Comment: I see, but how are those contents being output? Can you post the file?

Comment: Is it just plain html in the header?

Comment: I saw that, glad you got it sorted.